# How to get return value from Task wait()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, async-await

I have one async method which return value and I want to add wait to this task.

```
var return = Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(param1)).Wait();
```

How can I get return value from above this line.

Comment: why does not `var return = await SomeMethod()` work for you?

Comment: How does `SomeMethod`'s signature look like?

Comment: FWIW, you can't use `return` like that, this generates a `1002` error (reserved keyword), choose a different name. Also you can't append `Wait` like that, generates a `CS0815` => `can't assign method group to variable`. If you really want to wait.... `var t = Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(param1)); t.Wait(); Console.WriteLine(t.Result);`.

Comment: `return` is a reserved keyword , you can't use it as a regular variable name without prefixing it with `@` e.g. `var @return = Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(param1)).Wait();`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The typical method would be to just write

```
 var result = Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(param1)).Result;
```

This will block until the result becomes available. So it is equivalent to

```
var task = Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(param1));
task.Wait();
return task.Result;
```

Note that using `.Result` is generally not recommended. It will block the calling thread, so there is little point not just using `var result = SomeMethod(param1)`. There is also the risk of deadlocks. If this is run on the UI thread, and SomeMethod uses `.Invoke` or something else that waits for the UI thread, then your program will deadlock.

The generally recommended method is to use async/await: `var result = await Task.Run(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = await Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(param1));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.